# Sql Server Transaction dont work correctly

Tags: sql-server

I have a big problem with Sql Server (2008 R2).
In one database i have 3 table for example Tmp_table and T_Dest1 and T_Dest2
and I have 3 procedure that work with this 3 table

```
procedure Main()
Begin

  Declare @Res_Two int, @Res_Tree Int;

  Begin Transaction T_One;
    do heavy work;
    exec @Res_Two = two;--Call Procedure Two
    if @Res_Two = -1 
    Begin
      GoTo RB;
    End;

    do heavy work;
    exec @Res_Three = Three;--Call Procedure Tree
    if @Res_Three = -1 
    Begin
      GoTo RB;
    End;

    Delete From Tmp_table;

    if @@ERROR > 0
    Begin
    RB:
      Rollback Tran T_One;
      Return (-1);
    End Else Begin
      Commit Tran T_One;
      Return (1);
    End;
End;

End;

Procedure Two;
Begin
  insert into T_Dest1 Select * from tmp_table ;
  if @@ERROR > 0 Goto Rb;

  if @@ERROR > 0 
  Begin
  RB: 
   Return (-1);
  End Else Begin
   Return (1);
  End
End;

Procedure Three;
Begin
  insert into T_Dest2 Select * from tmp_table ;
  if @@ERROR > 0 Goto Rb;

  if @@ERROR > 0 
  Begin
  RB: 
    Return (-1);
  End Else Begin
    Return (1);
  End

End;
```

all things is OK, but suddenly when user call Main Proc data from tmp_table copy in T_Dest1 but dont copy in T_Dest2 and Main proc return 1 that means every thing is OK; (this state maybe occur one or two in day).

how i can what is incorrect in my db and what is my mistake?
this way that i use from transaction is correct?
can i find when data Lose from Tmp_Table and Main Proc don't work correctly?
i thinks this fault when my server is very busy and many users work with database together.

Comment: Why all the GOTOs? This would be better using try/catch instead. As coded this will sort of handle errors but you have no way of knowing what the error is. Let the error bubble up to your main procedure and handle it there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some pseudocode using try/catch instead of GOTOs.

```
procedure Main()
Begin

    Begin Transaction;

    begin try

        Declare @Res_Two int, @Res_Tree Int;


        do heavy work;
        exec two;--Call Procedure Two

        do heavy work;
        exec Three;--Call Procedure Tree

        Delete From Tmp_table;

        Commit Transaction;

    end try
    begin catch
        rollback transaction
        --Do some other to indicate the error like logging
        --Do something to inform caller that an error happened (return statement or raiserror)
    end catch
End;


Procedure Two;
Begin
  insert into T_Dest1 Select * from tmp_table ;
End;

Procedure Three;
Begin
  insert into T_Dest2 Select * from tmp_table ;
End;
```

Comment: i wrote this procedure before  (on sql 2000)

Comment: OK. So fix it now that it is broken and you have to open it up anyway. This would be the time to update it to modern constructs and syntax so it is more robust.